# Plugins loaded multiple times and build processes fails

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

For some reason, I'm experiencing that my phonegap project is generating a lot of different, including the lacking ability to build.

I have the following config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.qrreader" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>My Example QR Reader</name>
    <description>
        Example QR Reader
    </description>
    <author email="me@example.com" href="http://example.com">
        Repox
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="~6.0.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-qrscanner" spec="~2.5.0" />
    <icon src="www/res/icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="60" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="120" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="180" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="76" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="152" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="40" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="80" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="29" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="58" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="50" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="100" src="www/res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icons/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />
    <splash src="www/res/splash.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="2048" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1536" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1334" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="2208" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash gap:platform="ios" height="1242" src="www/res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
        <string>To read QR codes</string>
    </gap:config-file>

</widget>
```

With the plain example HTML file, the console tells me that my application is trying to load the cordova plugins multiple times:

```
...
Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.notification already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.notification already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.Vibration already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ Vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.Vibration already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ Vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.Vibration already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ Vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.Vibration already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ Vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.Vibration already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ Vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-vibration.Vibration already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ Vibration.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-qrscanner.QRScanner already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ www.min.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ barcodescanner.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ barcodescanner.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ barcodescanner.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ barcodescanner.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ barcodescanner.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ barcodescanner.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-qrscanner.QRScannerProxy already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ plugin.min.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScannerProxy already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ BarcodeScannerProxy.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScannerProxy already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ BarcodeScannerProxy.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScannerProxy already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ BarcodeScannerProxy.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScannerProxy already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ BarcodeScannerProxy.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScannerProxy already defined
define @ cordova.js:79
(anonymous) @ BarcodeScannerProxy.js:1
cordova.js:79 Uncaught module phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.BarcodeScannerProxy already defined
....
```

I suspect that these things also causes my builds to fail; I can no longer build my IOS or Android apps via Phonegap Build.

The log for the android built says the following:

BUILD FAILED

```
Total time: 13.921 secs
Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/project/AndroidManifest.xml:31:5-90 Error:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:31:5-90 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-65
/project/AndroidManifest.xml:32:5-85 Error:
    Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:32:5-85 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:30:5-84
/project/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I have no idea where to look for solutions for my issues; I can't figure out why the modules are trying to load multiple times nor why the builds suddenly fails.

Comment: try removing the plugs in question, and add one by one to locate what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From searching around](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/418), it appears as though you've stumbled upon an [interesting Android issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510751/cordova-android-duplicated-uses-feature-from-two-plugins). Basically, two or more referenced plugins are adding duplicate permission entries to the AndroidManifest.xml file similar to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Unfortunately, since you're using PhoneGap Build, you can't edit the AndroidManifest file.  Using your config above, I was able to build successfully by removing the Barcode Scanner plugin line:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="~6.0.6" />
```

I'm guessing that the QR Scanner and Camera plugins also specify CAMERA permissions. Do you need all three? One plugin may bundle in the others' functionality. Otherwise, you'd need to fork the plugin(s), update their AndroidManifest permissions and recompile them - not an easy task.

Comment: You got me in the right direction; the issue is caused by the phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner - removing it fixed it.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help.