# Why Is Android My App "Unsupported" by Chromebooks?

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, ionic2, chromebook

I know there are other similar questions on SO, but none of them addresses this directly.

My AndroidManifest.xml has this section in it:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

How can I tell what among those is resulting in Play Console telling listing Chromebooks as unsupported? Or if it's something else entirely?

*** UPDATE ***

I got to the point where my Manifest looked like this, and Play Console still did not indicate Chromebooks as supported devices, so I'm at a loss.

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$NFCStateChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" required="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all Chromebooks will have touch-screens, or GPS. These should be optional, not required.

Try this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" required="false" />
```

You may have to modify your code to account GPS not being present.

Comment: I'm struggling with how to make this happen with ionic2 / cordova, my best efforts are resulting in `Element uses-feature#android.hardware.location.gps duplicated` build errors. And I'm pretty sure this is happening because of declarations in the cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin.

Comment: I'm using ionic2, not phonegap, and there's nothing in my manifest that would imply telephony or camera afaict.

Comment: Then how about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510751/cordova-android-duplicated-uses-feature-from-two-plugins/35597820)? I answered your original question, now it is up to you to use the suggestion. I gave you the answer I could. Now I am just Googling, which you too have the ability to do. I never said you needed to use telephony of the camera, I simply shared that link as an example. You would change out your permissions to fit.

Comment: No worries, believe me I have been hunting for this for a couple of days, and I certainly don't expect you to Google for me :-). I'm very appreciative of the help you've already offered. Didn't mean to sound rude at all.