# ionic cordova run android encountered an error

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I am using @ionic-native/qr-scanner, when i try to make build by ionic cordova run android it throws an error

*Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-60 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:19:
5-85*

*Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-65 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xm
l:18:5-90*

and found multiple entries in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: See this please. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212727/3596415 Hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there was a response on [Github](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/issues/104)

> fixed it by using either the qr code scanner or the barcode scanner it
> seems like you can't use both.

Courtesy of SidaouiBilel

Comment: i am only using qr-scanner

Comment: Have you tried looking in platforms/android. Looking through AndroidManifest.xml and editing, or even sharing the content of  the file - maybe backing it up first somewhere and manually removing duplicates...

Comment: Are there other Cordova plugins in your project?

Comment: yes i have tried to manually removed the duplicate entries but didn't work

Comment: How about the config.xml. Is a plugin somehow listed twice in there under platform-name="android"? If nothing seems amiss, how about deleting the platform folder and doing uninstall/install of plugins perhaps? then do the build again ...Backup your project folder first...